# Where to find general A320 E&E Compartment Information?

Tags: avionics, airbus-a320, electrical-system

I'm student in electrical engineering and write my thesis on some topic of the e&e compartment. The main focus is on the computers of the A320 flightcraft, actually called E&E Compartment. Sadly because of closed source of this avionics part there is no general information of what it is. This is also clear why, most infos can only accessed by technician because of several security reasons. But maybe there is still some general descriptions and pictures that shows for example the location of e&e and text like: e&e has distributed system architecture where each computer has specific role, they are all connected by arinc... blabla.. and similiar and so on :)

It can be all, books, patents, googling keywords.. It would all help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term E&E is used only in Boeings aircraft. For Airbus try to Google "avionics compartment" as this is the correct term.

This specific data you Will find in wiring diagram manual and schematic diagram manual, sadly due the complexity of the systems you won't find only one file for all systems.

Comment: You mentioned that there is only one file for all systems. Do you have something specific? Is it possible to share at least the name of the document?

Answer (score 0):

After good amount of search, I have found that the ATA 100 [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATA_100) documents of A320 explain pretty well each system of a flight craft. This is a standardised set of docs that help organise data for MRO's and pilots.

The only problem is that most documents are somewhere in MRO companies. But several documents were nevertheless uploaded by some guys. If you search in google for example "A320 ATA 31" (and varying similiar) than you get different "book stores" where people around the world upload partly or fully this documents. Dates of this docs can vary from 1990 to 2018.

One example would be the A320 ATA 31 Indicating/Recording Systems, that describes very detailed PFD, ND, DMC, SDAC, ECAM and all other "cockpit" systems. Here the [link](https://de.scribd.com/document/336828033/CHAPTER-31-pdf).

My original question was more generally, but this docs helped me to understand a lot about this aircraft.